# select query on a table with many rows (250m+ rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a select statement that takes a while (a very long time) for MySQL to complete. All tables are "MyISAM". MySQL version is 5.6.41.

I have three tables

- table 1: 50,000 rows
- table 2: 7,500,000 rows (7.5GB)
- table 3: 250,000,000 rows (17.5GB)

I perform a select statement with the left joins on the table.

```
select `table1`.* 
from `table1`  
inner join `table2` on `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
inner join `table3` on `table3`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` 
where `table1`.`id` = "2" and `table3`.`parameter` = 'param'
```

---

"id" columns are primary keys and "parameter" column has index applied on it

Current table code

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `id` (`id`), 
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `table1_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `id` (`id`), 
    INDEX `table1_id_index` (`table1_id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE `table3` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `table2_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `parameter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `id` (`id`), 
    INDEX `id` (`parameter`), 
    INDEX `table2_id_index` (`table1_id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

---

The odd thing is that when i re-write the query other way round i have no performance issues:

```
select `table1`.* 
from `table3`  
inner join `table2` on `table3`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` 
inner join `table1` on `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
where `table1`.`id` = "2" and `table3`.`parameter` = 'param'
```

Comment: Are you asking how you might speed this up? If so, do you have indexes for any of these tables yet? If not, adding an index on each table for the `id` field would probably help a ton here.

Comment: Well. do you have the proper indexes applied, and are they getting used?

Comment: As for the `like '%param%'` portion perhaps look into [`Full-Text Search`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and a `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: Do you really want to get all the columns from `table1`. Generally, it is not the case. Consider fetching only those columns which you really need in your application. Check: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: If your problem is low speed of the query, then create this index on table3: `CREATE INDEX my_fast_index ON table3( table2_id, parameter )`

Comment: which data type is the column id in table1 ??

Comment: column id is integer

Comment: Check for typo in INDEX `table2_id_index` (`table1_id`),

Comment: `KEY(id)` is totally redundant with `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  Keep the PK; drop the other.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have proper index  for id and be sure you don't perform unuseful data conversion 
and for

```
create index  idx1 on table2 (table1_id, id) 
create index  idx2 on table3 (table2_id, parameter)
```

Comment: indexing parameter won't help in this instance :-(

Comment: what would help?

Comment: @user3402600  the indices shown are more efficient than the individual indices

Comment: @Strawberry - `(table2_id, param)` is at least "covering", thereby avoiding a disk seek for _every_ lookup.  Flipping the order optimizes it for starting with `table3`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to InnoDB.  It "clusters" the `PRIMARY KEY` with the data, thereby avoiding several random seeks that you are suffering from with MyISAM.

Meanwhile, what is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  How much RAM do you have?